# Finding X-intercept using basic algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

This always become a problem for me when there is a fraction in an equation, everything just tends to be harder. I multiplied by $3$ on both sides to get rid of $\frac{1}{3}$ making the equation become $3y = x^3-6x^2-15x+6$ and I tried using "synthetic division" but I couldn't get the remainder to become $0$. Is there any simpler way to figure this out? I am just trying to find $x$-axis intercept point, where $y = 0$.

The problem is in the image

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jEsG.png)

Comment: Are you allowed to use a graphing calculator to find your answer? If so, what make/model?

Comment: TI-84 is the only calculator allowed

Comment: Oh, then on the TI-84 I believe there's an option to find the zeroes.

Comment: How do you go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a plot of the equation:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3-6*x%5E2-15*x%2B6
```

Looking at a plot and considering the rational root theorem, I do not believe the equation has any rational roots. Have you thought about using some numerical analysis technique such as the bisection method?

Comment: Bisection method? Do you have an example for that?

Comment: I do not have an example, but for more information about the bisection method, I refer you to the following URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method